# Stripe checkout using debit card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe with rails application. I have interfaced with credit card (Ref link: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial). Its working fine. Now i need to interface with debit card. I couldn't get the idea of processing payment with debit card. Could someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-cards-and-payment-types-can-i-accept-with-stripe), any kind of credit and debit card will be accepted. That means if your integration already works for credit cards then it will work for debit cards too.

Comment: For credit card, once the user enters the card details (card holder name, number, cvv, exp) then stripetoken will be generated on submit and sent to server side. Which can be used for charging. But debit card requires otp or password section right? @zamakkat

Comment: What you are referring to is 3DS Secure where the payment details will be confirmed with a secondary authentication. It is not exclusive to debit cards and needs a specific implementation from the client. As of writing, [Stripe does not support 3DS Secure](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-3d-secure-verified-by-visa-mastercard-securecode)